# MySQL Multiple Columns Sum() in different / multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I have basic table looking like:

[image]

When I am using the Query:

`SELECT *, SUM(cr) AS cr, SUM(dr) AS dr  FROM my_table GROUP BY  id`

I am getting:

[image]

and that's correct!

What's the proper query to get (each sum in different row):

[image]

I already tried `GROUP BY ID,CR,DR` and `GROUP BY CR,DR,ID` but with not the results that I wanted. (I don't care if the 0 values are also NULL)

Comment: Create two tables by using " SELECT *, SUM(cr) AS cr  FROM my_table GROUP BY  id" and "SELECT *, SUM(dr) AS dr  FROM my_table GROUP BY  id" and join the two tables by ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
select id, sum(dr) as dr, 0 as cr from my_table group by id
union all
select id, 0, sum(cr) from my_table group by id
order by id, dr desc
```